# Values of array of structs suddenly change (?)

Tags: c, arrays, struct

So I've been looking to this code for hours and I can't seem to understand what is happening, despite my efforts to debug this with printf's everywhere. The following function is where my main problem is:

```
void drawFolders() {

printf("Going to call getSubFolder\n");
getSubFolders(".");

printf("DEBUG 1 - Return from getFolderName is: %s\n", getFolderName(3));

printf("DEBUG 2 - Return from getFolderName is: %s\n", getFolderName(5));

int k;

for(k = 0; k < getNumberFolders(); k++) {
    printf("DEBUG INLOOP %d - Return from getFolderName is: %s\n",k, getFolderName(k));


    draw_sprite(k*60 + 30, 50, folder);

    //draw_string(temp[i].name,i*60 + 30, 50);

}
```

}

Basically, in DEBUG1 and DEBUG2 my function getFolderName() seems to work just fine, ie, a string is returned with no problems. However, when I try to call this function inside my for loop, all I get from getFolderName is garbage (**except** the first one) , even when k is 3 or 5 (cases which I've tested before the for loop and worked fine). k is not wrong, as I print it too. getFolderName does nothing to the array , here is the function :

```
char* getFolderName(int index) {
printf("Values inside getFolderName() function : %s\n", currentFolders[index].name);
return currentFolders[index].name ;
```

}

Also it might be important to show what currentFolders is:

```
typedef struct Directories {

    char* name;
    int active;

} Directory;

Directory currentFolders[30];
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Dec 20 22:18:48 192 kernel: Vai chamar o getSubFolder
Dec 20 22:18:48 192 kernel: Values inside getSubFolders function: .
Dec 20 22:18:48 192 kernel: Values inside getSubFolders function: ..
Dec 20 22:18:48 192 kernel: Values inside getSubFolders function: usr
Dec 20 22:18:48 192 kernel: Values inside getSubFolders function: lab4
Dec 20 22:18:48 192 kernel: Values inside getSubFolders function: proj
Dec 20 22:18:48 192 kernel: Values inside getSubFolders function: bin
Dec 20 22:18:48 192 kernel: Values inside getSubFolders function: boot
Dec 20 22:18:48 192 kernel: Values inside getSubFolders function: dev
Dec 20 22:18:48 192 kernel: Values inside getSubFolders function: etc
Dec 20 22:18:48 192 kernel: Values inside getSubFolders function: home
Dec 20 22:18:48 192 kernel: Values inside getSubFolders function: mnt
Dec 20 22:18:48 192 kernel: Values inside getSubFolders function: root
Dec 20 22:18:48 192 kernel: Values inside getSubFolders function: sbin
Dec 20 22:18:48 192 kernel: Values inside getSubFolders function: tmp
Dec 20 22:18:48 192 kernel: Values inside getSubFolders function: var
Dec 20 22:18:48 192 kernel: DEBUG 0Values inside getFolderName() function : lab4
Dec 20 22:18:48 192 kernel: DEBUG 1 - Return from getFolderName is: lab4
Dec 20 22:18:48 192 kernel: Values inside getFolderName() function : bin
Dec 20 22:18:48 192 kernel: DEBUG 2 - Return from getFolderName is: bin
Dec 20 22:18:48 192 kernel: Values inside getFolderName() function : .
Dec 20 22:18:48 192 kernel: DEBUG INLOOP 0 - Return from getFolderName is: .
Dec 20 22:18:48 192 kernel: Values inside getFolderName() function : 
Dec 20 22:18:48 192 kernel: DEBUG INLOOP 1 - Return from getFolderName is: 
Dec 20 22:18:48 192 kernel: Values inside getFolderName() function : 
Dec 20 22:18:48 192 kernel: DEBUG INLOOP 2 - Return from getFolderName is: 
Dec 20 22:18:48 192 kernel: Values inside getFolderName() function : 
Dec 20 22:18:48 192 kernel: DEBUG INLOOP 3 - Return from getFolderName is: 
Dec 20 22:18:48 192 kernel: Values inside getFolderName() function : 
Dec 20 22:18:48 192 kernel: DEBUG INLOOP 4 - Return from getFolderName is: 
Dec 20 22:18:48 192 kernel: Values inside getFolderName() function : 
Dec 20 22:18:48 192 kernel: DEBUG INLOOP 5 - Return from getFolderName is: 
Dec 20 22:18:48 192 kernel: Values inside getFolderName() function : 
Dec 20 22:18:48 192 kernel: DEBUG INLOOP 6 - Return from getFolderName is: 
Dec 20 22:18:48 192 kernel: Values inside getFolderName() function : 
Dec 20 22:18:48 192 kernel: DEBUG INLOOP 7 - Return from getFolderName is: 
Dec 20 22:18:48 192 kernel: Values inside getFolderName() function : 
Dec 20 22:18:48 192 kernel: DEBUG INLOOP 8 - Return from getFolderName is: 
Dec 20 22:18:48 192 kernel: Values inside getFolderName() function : 
Dec 20 22:18:48 192 kernel: DEBUG INLOOP 9 - Return from getFolderName is: 
Dec 20 22:18:48 192 kernel: Values inside getFolderName() function : 
Dec 20 22:18:48 192 kernel: DEBUG INLOOP 10 - Return from getFolderName is: 
Dec 20 22:18:48 192 kernel: Values inside getFolderName() function : 
Dec 20 22:18:48 192 kernel: DEBUG INLOOP 11 - Return from getFolderName is: 
Dec 20 22:18:48 192 kernel: Values inside getFolderName() function : 
Dec 20 22:18:48 192 kernel: DEBUG INLOOP 12 - Return from getFolderName is: 
Dec 20 22:18:48 192 kernel: Values inside getFolderName() function : 
Dec 20 22:18:48 192 kernel: DEBUG INLOOP 13 - Return from getFolderName is: 
Dec 20 22:18:48 192 kernel: Values inside getFolderName() function : 
Dec 20 22:18:48 192 kernel: DEBUG INLOOP 14 - Return from getFolderName is:
```

Other function called that isn't related to the problem, I think, but you might want to take a look so here it is anyway:

```
  int getSubFolders(char* foldername) {
    num_folders = 0;

    struct dirent *de=NULL;
      DIR *d=NULL;

      d=opendir(foldername);
      if(d == NULL) {
        perror("Couldn't open directory");
        return(2);
      }

      int i = 0;
      // Loop while not NULL
      while(de = readdir(d)) {
        num_folders++;
        Directory temp;
        currentFolders[i].name = de->d_name;

        strcpy( currentFolders[i].name, de->d_name);

//      printf("nome %s\n",de->d_name);

        //printf("temp.name %s\n",temp.name);

      //  currentFolders[i] = temp;

        printf("Values inside getSubFolders function: %s\n",currentFolders[i].name);

        i++;
      }

      printCurrentFolders();

      closedir(d);
      return(0);

}
```

Comment: `currentFolders[i].name = de->d_name;` copies the address of `de->d_name`, but not its contents.  The next line `strcpy( currentFolders[i].name, de->d_nam` copy the data to itself.  Code needs to allocate memory.

Comment: Still not answering why would it work outside of the for loop and not inside of it? Have you read all of that or just insta downvoted after 2 lines?

Comment: You have undefined behavior, calling `strcpy` with both arguments pointing to the same address, the shouldn't even overlap.

Comment: True - my comment is not an answer, that is why it is in the comment section.  Consider it an idea for yourself or others to answer completely.  And its not my down-vote but will be now.

Comment: the problem was there before strcpy, exactly the same. So that's not the problem either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix it this way, the struct declare it like this

```
typedef struct Directories {
    char name[256];
    int active;
} Directory;
```

and remove this line

```
currentFolders[i].name = de->d_name;
```

The problem is caused by `closedir(d);` cleaning up resources used by `opendir`, the `struct dirent *` being part of those resources.

Comment: Thankyou, that worked. :) 5 lines that anyone could have typed but instead they just preferred to downvote. Thanks a lot for your answer, I'd upvote but I'm left with 5 points of rep after this question so really can't do it. Cheers

Comment: You can just accept the answer if it worked for you.

Comment: Done, and thanks again for the further explanation. Would never get there by myself